# Sharepoint: Redirect user from frontpage to subsite

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I have a Sharepoint 2007 site which has a frontpage and then various sub-sites. One of our usergroups only have access to one of these subsites and **not** the frontpage. However, due to the way they access the site, they will always land on the frontpage, which currently presents them with the default "access denied" page.

Is there some way to redirect these users to their subsite before they get presented with the access denied page?

All solutions are welcome, and solutions that include programming and feature/solution deployment is not an issue. The solutions is only for this single usergroup, so hardcoding (even if it is ugly) the user group and destination URL is an acceptable solution.

EDIT: I heard a custom accessdenied.aspx page as a suggestion, but it seems to be a rather cumbersome alteration for a simple feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One dirty solution is to replace AccessDenied.aspx page, in Layouts folder, and add your own logic. You can check the current user and see if he has permission to "Sub site" then redirect him.

This is not a recommended solution as Service Packs to SharePoint can replace AccessDenied.aspx file.

Comment: Yeah, this was an option I considered. In the end I have gone with a HttpModule (not SP specific) that intercepts the request and redirects the user if he is part of the specific group.